# Unable to see ECS clusters from AWS CLI or boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

I've created a few clusters using AWS ECS to run my workflows. So far, I've been managing their provisioning / task definition through a combination of Terraform and the console.

Today, I wanted to use `boto3` to add in some logic checks for tasks that were already running. However, when I tried to list my clusters, the client return an empty list:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
client = session.client('ecs')
print(client.list_clusters())
```

> {'clusterArns': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId':
>   'XXX', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
>   'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid':
>   'XXX', 'content-type':
>   'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '18', 'date': 'Fri, 18
>   Jan 2019 15:09:33 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

This is baffling to me because I've made sure to use my default profile, and when I log into my ECS console, I see my clusters (there's more, but I am just showing one):
[image]

Moreover, I am able to list all of my S3 buckets with no issue:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all(): 
        print(bucket.name)
```

The above code returns a complete list of my S3 buckets. I've read through the documentation for ECS `boto3` but am stuck as to why my clusters are not being found.

Comment: check the region for your default profile and make sure it matches with where you created your test cluster.

Comment: @Asdfg that was it. I feel silly for that oversight! Yikes. Being able to list from S3 (which is a global resource) vs. ECS which is region specific should have been the tip off.

Comment: If you'd like, go ahead and answer that and I'll accept it.

Comment: been there, done that. Once I deleted all the EC2 instances in a region which we were using instead of region which we decided to decommission. Long live CFTs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the region for your default profile and make sure it matches with where you created your test cluster.